# How to get "From Form" Event to show up in Triggers?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to figure out how to get "From Form" to show up in my event triggers.

I have a form connected to a spreadsheet and have an on submit function in one script and two other separate function in the same project.

I somehow successfully allowed one function to trigger on the forms submission. However, I added a new script to the project and am only getting the calendar and time driven options.

How can I add the From Form option to the new script?

Thanks!

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvAjr.png)

Comment: Why are you triggering multiple functions from a single event? Trigger one function, and in that function, call the desired additional methods: `function giveMeTheTrigger(event) { foo(event); bar(event); baz(event); }`

Comment: I was able to resolve this by opening up the form and then from the form going to the script editor and it added the available triggers for me.